# AngularJS Calculating product prices with multiple select options

Tags: forms, angularjs, select

Summary:

Users should be choosing their desired products in a form environment. Every product has a core price and multiple additional options available which change the price when selected.

Products and options are shown in two SELECT fields which are getting populated like this:

```
$scope.products = [
{
    name:'Product A',
    cost:5,
    options: [{name:"Option 1", value:10}]
},

{
    name:'Product B',
    cost:10,
    options: [{name:"Option 1", value:10},{name:"Option 2", value:15}]
}
];

$scope.cart = {
    items: [{            
        qty: 1,
    }]
};
```

and

```
<tr ng:repeat="item in cart.items">
  <td>
    <div class="type-select">
      <select ng-model="item.product" ng-options="p.name for p in products"></select>
    </div>      
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="type-select">
      <select ng-model="item.option" ng-options="o for o in item.product.options.name" ng- disabled="!checked">
    </div>         
  </td>    
  <td>
    <input ng:model="item.qty" value="1" size="4" ng:required="" ng:validate="integer" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required input-mini">
  </td>
  <td>
     {{calculate()}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

1. <strike>The options select stays empty. Why?</strike>
2. How can i calculate this the angular way? (There will be multiple lines of product possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="item.product" ng-options="p as p.name for p in products">
</select>
...
<select ng-model="item.option" ng-options="o as o.name for o in 
item.product.options" ng-disabled="!checked"></select>
...
<td>
    {{calculate(item)}}
</td>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.calculate = function(item){
    /* return the calculated cost */        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find my example app airquotes a good reference: https://github.com/JohnMunsch/airquotes

It's an AngularJS app I wrote for a t-shirt site and it demonstrates generating quotes on the fly given a set of different values the user may set that can affect the price (such as darker colors having a surcharge because more ink has to be used when screen printing them and xxl shirts have a price premium).

It sounds like it's a good match for the kind of thing you're trying to build here.

Comment: Cool, Thanks alot will definately check out!